# else statement no being accessed in php if statement

Tags: php, validation, mysqli

I am writing a log in script for a site, I have most things working except on a validation mysqli query the else tatement is not being accessed and I cannot figure out how to resolve it, the code below is the index page that has the html and then the php script that is called, All of the php validation works except for the bit of script that validates all the input fields match the database fields, i can get the validation side of the if statement to work and it sends me to the relevent page, the problem is that if the validation in the first part of the if statement shows invalid it doesnt then pass to the else statement, all i get is a blank white page and it is the same as the php page doing the validation not the page i need it to go too. Any help would be most appreciated.

HTML CODE ***********

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dot Mov Home</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="/styles/home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/lemon:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/civem.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/pswrd_strength.js"></script>
<script src="/js/email_dbvalidate.js"></script>
<script src="/js/username_dbvalidate.js"></script>
<script src="/js/confirm_password__dbvalidate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function SwapDivsWithClick(div1,div2)
{
   d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
   d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
   if( d2.style.display == "none" )
   {
      d1.style.display = "none";
      d2.style.display = "block";
   }
   else
   {
      d1.style.display = "block";
      d2.style.display = "none";
   }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="video_container">
  <video muted autoplay loop >
    <source src="/video/South Dakota Badlands Scenic Byway 720p (Video Only)_1.3gp" type="video/3gp">
    <source src="/video/South Dakota Badlands Scenic Byway 720p (Video Only).webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="/video/South Dakota Badlands Scenic Byway 720p.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser. </video>
</div>

<header>

  <div class="upload"><a href="upload.html" title="Upload" target="_self">UPLOAD</a></div>
        <div class="view"><a href="view.php" title="View" target="_self">VIEW</a></div>
            <div class="spacer1"></div>

                <div class="search_bar">
                  <form action="/search_results.php" method="post" name="search_database" autocomplete="on">
                    <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search">
                  </form>


    </div>
                <div class="logo_text">.MOV </div>
                <div class="tagline">Motorcycle Online Video</div>
</a></header>
<main>

  <div id="login" style="display:block">




            <form method="post" action="includes/login.inc.php" id="loginform">


                <input name="email" type="email" id="email" form="loginform" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email">


                <input name="password" type="password" id="password" form="loginform" placeholder="Please Enter Your Password" title="Please Enter Your Password">


<div class="submit_buttons">
          <input type="submit" class="login_btn" form="loginform" formaction="includes/login.inc.php" title="Login" value="Login">

<a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('login','join')"><div class="join_but">Or Join</div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="forgotten_password">Forgotten Password</div>
        <div class="login_statements">
                      <div class="statement1">
                        <div class="by_joining">By Joining</div>
                        <div class="dot_mov">.MOV</div>
                        <div class="agree">You agree to our</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="statement2">
                        <div class="terms_link"><a href="terms.html" title="Terms of Service" target="_self">Terms of Service</a></div>
                        <div class="and">and</div>
                        <div class="service_link"><a href="privacy.html" title="Privacy Policy" target="_self">Privacy Policy</a></div>
                      </div>

              </div>
                    <div class="facebook_login">
                        <div class="facebook_icon"><img src="images/fb.png" class="fb_icon"></div>
                        <div class="fb_link">Login with FaceBook </div>
              </div>
    </form>
  </div>                  


  </div>


  <div id="join" style="display: none;">




    <form action="includes/register.inc.php" method="post" id="joinform">

                <input name="name2" type="text" id="name2" form="joinform" placeholder="Please Enter Your Username" title="Please Enter Your Username">
                <div id="user-name">
         <h4>Username must meet the following requirements!<br>If you have forgotten your Password, click on "Forgotten Password"!</h4> 

                <div id="name_result"></div>
                <div id="name_length" class="invalid">At least <strong>6 letters</strong></div>


                </div>


                <input name="email2" type="email" id="email2" form="joinform" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email" title="Please Enter a Valid Email">
                <div id="user-email">
         <h4>Email must be a valid Email format!<br>If the Email exists, Either Login using the Username the Email was setup with or check your Email is correct!</h4>
                <div id="email_result">
                <div id="email_validate" class="invalid">Email Valid</div>
                <div id="emaildb_validate"></div>
</div>

      </div>


      <input name="password2" type="password" id="password2" form="joinform" placeholder="Please Enter Your Password" title="Please Enter Your Password">
<div id="pswd_info">
    <h4>Password must meet the following requirements!<br>If the Password doesnt meet the requirements you will be required to fill in the form again!</h4>
    <ul id="pswd_list">
        <li id="letter" class="invalid">At least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
        <li id="capital" class="invalid">At least <strong>one capital letter</strong></li>
        <li id="number" class="invalid">At least <strong>one number</strong></li>
        <li id="length" class="invalid">Be at least <strong>8 characters</strong></li>
    </ul>
</div>

                <input name="confirm_password2" type="password" id="confirm_password2" form="joinform" placeholder="Please Confirm Your Password" title="Please Confirm Your Password">
            <div id="user-confirm_password">
       <h4>Please Confirm Password<br>If the Passwords do not match, you wil be required to fill in the form again!</h4>     

      <div id="error" class="error"></div>
            <div id="confirm_match" class="invalid">Passwords Match</div>




      </div>

      <div class="submit_buttons2">
                    <input name="join_btn2" type="submit" id="join_btn2" form="joinform" formaction="includes/register.inc.php" " formmethod="POST" title="Join" value="Join">

<a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('login','join')"><div class="join_btn2">Or Login</div></a>
</div>


                                <div class="login_statements2">
                      <div class="statement1">
                        <div class="by_joining">By Joining</div>
                        <div class="dot_mov">.MOV</div>
                        <div class="agree">You agree to our</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="statement2">
                        <div class="terms_link"><a href="terms.html" title="Terms of Service" target="_self">Terms of Service</a></div>
                        <div class="and">and</div>
                        <div class="service_link"><a href="privacy.html" title="Privacy Policy" target="_self">Privacy Policy</a></div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="facebook_login2">
                        <div class="facebook_icon"><img src="images/fb.png" class="fb_icon"></div>
                        <div class="fb_link">Login with FaceBook </div>
                        </div>
      </form>
  </div>                  




              </div>

  </div>
  <div class="scroll_container">
    <a data-scroll href="#body2"><div class="scroll_link">
      <div class="arrow"><img src="/images/arrow.png" alt="" class="arrow_icon"/></div>

      <div class="arrow3"><img src="/images/arrow.png" alt="" class="arrow_icon"/></div>
    Scroll Down</div></a>
  </div>







</main>

<div class="body2" id="body2">

  <div class="vid_grid">

    <div class="top_section">
        <div class="top_left_quarter"></div>
        <div class="top_right_quarter">
          <div class="top_right_left_quarter"></div>
          <div class="top_right_right_quarter"></div>
          <div class="top_right_bottom_left"></div>
          <div class="top_right_bottom_right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom_section">
      <div class="bottpm_left_top"></div>
      <div class="bottpm_left_bottom"></div>
      <div class="bottom_middle"></div>     
        <div class="bottom_left_quarter"></div>
        <div class="bottom_right_quarter"></div>
        <div class="bottom_right_top"></div>
        <div class="bottom_right_bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="/staff_picks.php"><div class="staff_picks">Staff Picks </div></a>


  </div>

</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <div id="breadcrumbs"><a href="/terms.html" title="Terms" target="_self">Terms</a> &vert; <a href="/privacy.html" title="Privacy" target="_self">Privacy</a> &vert; <a href="/about.html" title="About Us" target="_self">About Us</a> &vert; <a href="/copyright.html" title="Copyright" target="_self">Copyright</a> &vert; <a href="/cookies.html" title="Cookies" target="_self">Cookies</a> &vert; &reg &copy 2015</div><img src="/images/.mov.png" alt="" width="42" height="14" class="logo"/>
  <div class="social_media"><img src="/images/fb.png" alt="" width="30" height="30" class="fbicon"/><img src="/images/twitter.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="twittericon"/><img src="/images/googleplus.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="googleplusicon"/></div>



</footer>
<script src="/js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="/js/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        smoothScroll.init({
            speed: 1000,
            easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
            offset: 0,
            updateURL: true,
            callbackBefore: function ( toggle, anchor ) {},
            callbackAfter: function ( toggle, anchor ) {}
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP ***************

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start();

$emailErr = $passwordErr = $password_matchErr = $email_exsistErr = '';
$email = $name = $password = $confirm_password = '';



if (isset($_POST['name2'], $_POST['email2'], $_POST['paswword2'], $_POST['confirm_password2'])) {
    $error_msg .=  "please fill in the form"; 
    } else {

    // Sanitize the data passed in 'name'
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    // Sanitize the data passed in 'email'
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email2', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    // validate the data passed in 'email'
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

    // check if email is valid
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

        // Not a valid email
        $emailErr = "The email address you entered is not valid";
    }

    //Sanitize the data passed in 'password'
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    //validate the data passed in 'password'
    if (preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $password)) {
 } else {
        $passwordErr = "Password is invalid!<br>Please ensure your password is formatted as described when filling in the form!";
}           


    //Sanitize the data passed in 'confirm_password'
    $confirm_password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'confirm_password2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    //check that password and confirm password match
if ($password != $confirm_password) {

         // error matching passwords
$confirm_passwordErr = "Your passwords do not match.<br>Please type carefully.";
     }






$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM signed_up WHERE email = `'$email'");`  



while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {


    if ($row["name"] == $name && $row["email"] == $email && $row["password"] == $password) { 
$regErr = 'User Already Exsists!<br>Please Login';
$_SESSION['regErr'] = $regErr;
header('location: ../login.php');

} else {

//if ($emailErr == '' && $passwordErr == '' && $password_matchErr == '' && $email_exsistErr =='') {
echo '15';
        $_SESSION['emailErr'] = $emailErr;
        $_SESSION['passwordErr'] = $passwordErr;
        $_SESSION['confirm_passwordErr'] = $confirm_passwordErr;
        $_SESSION['email_exsistErr'] = $email_exsistErr;
header('Location: ../join.php');
exit();
    }
        }
    }
//}
 ?>
```

This is the section of code where the issue is ***********

```
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM signed_up WHERE email = '$email'");    

    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {


        if ($row["name"] == $name && $row["email"] == $email && $row["password"] == $password) { 
    $regErr = 'User Already Exsists!<br>Please Login';
    $_SESSION['regErr'] = $regErr;
    header('location: ../login.php');

    } else {

    //if ($emailErr == '' && $passwordErr == '' && $password_matchErr == '' && $email_exsistErr =='') {
    echo '15';
            $_SESSION['emailErr'] = $emailErr;
            $_SESSION['passwordErr'] = $passwordErr;
            $_SESSION['confirm_passwordErr'] = $confirm_passwordErr;
            $_SESSION['email_exsistErr'] = $email_exsistErr;
    header('Location: ../join.php');
    exit();
        }
            }
        }
    //}
     ?>
```

edited code that now works ***********************

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM signed_up WHERE email = '$email'");    

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {


    if ($row["name"] == $name && $row["email"] == $email && $row["password"] == $password) {

$regErr = 'User Already Exsists!<br>Please Login';
$_SESSION['regErr'] = $regErr;
header('location: ../login.php');

}else{   

        $_SESSION['emailErr'] = $emailErr;
        $_SESSION['passwordErr'] = $passwordErr;
        $_SESSION['confirm_passwordErr'] = $confirm_passwordErr;
        $_SESSION['email_exsistErr'] = $email_exsistErr;
header('Location: ../join.php');
exit();

}

}
        }
```

Comment: why are you comparing passwords for checking whether a user exists?

Comment: i was just validating every input to the database fields, I know its not necassary and i will probably remove before going live

Comment: any exceptions? or does your echo '15' show up?

Comment: no exceptions and no the echo '15' not showing up which i realise suggests the else statement isnt being accessed

Comment: what does this 'join.php' contain. empty page?

Comment: The join php contains the same form as the index page, but accepts and displays the errors defined in the session variables to send the errors to the join page to tell the user why the form wasnt validated

Comment: the first part of the if statement if all fields validate against the database sends the user to a login.php page that has a login form, the session variable is then echo'd in that page telling the user that the details of the join form were already in the database and that as all fields were validated so that user should use thse details to logon

Comment: Are ther any redirections in the join.php?

Comment: the join form uses the same php validation as the index page form

Comment: I have sussed it by changing my code as follows, taking out the curly brackets after the while statement and adding a semi colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your validation directly into SQL

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*) FROM signed_up WHERE email = '$email' AND name = '$name'"); 
if ($result->fetchColumn()){
    echo "User already exists";
}else{
    echo "New user";
}
```